# How can I use Trading View chart widget in Vue.Js Project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, tradingview-api

I'm trying to add Trading view charts to my Vue.js project but I cant find a way to use it.
Here's the html tag can anyone help me on how to use it?

```html
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_bf88f"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    new TradingView.widget(
    {
      "width": 980,
      "height": 610,
      "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
      "interval": "D",
      "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
      "theme": "dark",
      "style": "1",
      "locale": "en",
      "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
      "enable_publishing": false,
      "allow_symbol_change": true,
      "container_id": "tradingview_bf88f"
    }
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://github.com/lolitaframework/vue-trading-view) vue js components for tradingview real-time chart widget. I think this is exactly what you want.

**Updated Answer:**

Please pay attention that in current version of this component (1.0.1) there is a bug in documentation. You should import this component like this:

```
import VueTradingView from 'vue-trading-view/src/vue-trading-view';
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to use it, it didn't work and had no docs on how to use it . at least I couldn't do anything with the examples.

Comment: You are right! There is a bug in their github documention. I edit my answer. please read updated answer.

Comment: THANK YOU ! It worked
but I just have one more question. Do you know how I can pass data to the chart component ? I tried different things in the props of script section but I couldn't achieve anything. can you help me out with that too ? :)

Comment: Actually it is not possible to pass data to vue tradingview chart widget. Instead you can use [trading-vue-js](https://github.com/tvjsx/trading-vue-js) or [tradingview-lightweight-charts](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts) libraries.

Comment: So you mean I can only define height as a hard code ?

Comment: If you still haven't found a way, check this: https://github.com/ehsan-shv/vue-tradingviewWidgets

Answer (score 1):

The purest html/js way would be splitting to HTML/script and put them to:

< HTML >:

```
 <template lang='pug'>
    <!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
    <div class="tradingview-widget-container">
      <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
      <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/technicals/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL stock analysis</span></a> by TradingView</div>
    </div>
    <!-- TradingView Widget END -->
 </template>
```

< Script >:

```
mounted() {
const widgetPlaceholder = document.getElementsByClassName('tradingview-widget-container')[0];
widgetPlaceholder.replaceChildren(); // empty placeholder
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js'
script.async = true;
script.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
  "interval": "1h",
  "width": 425,
  "isTransparent": false,
  "height": 450,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "showIntervalTabs": true,
  "locale": "en",
  "colorTheme": "light"
});
widgetPlaceholder.appendChild(script);
},
```